# Parse Errors and Gone In

Tags: php

I am a newbie in coding so please accept my apologies if the explanation is not the best.

I have a php football event importer feed which been working fine for the past 6/7 months until last week I get these 3 errors:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start
>   tag expected, '<' not found in
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): 410 Gone in
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in

All the above are on line 110. Here is what my lines are starting from line 103:

```
protected function getXml() {
    $client = new HttpClient();
    $client->setAdapter('Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl');
    $client->setUri(self::FEED);
    $result = $client->send();
    $body   = $result->getBody();

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($body);
    if (false === $xml) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to open xml feed - ' . self::FEED);
    }
    return $xml;
}
```

Any help it is much appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: See the contents of `$body`

Comment: Validate the result of $result->getBody() or just open a file in Firefox for example. It looks like a corrupted source file.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in

Because your string [have to start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) with a xml tag for example     `<?xml version='..'?>` so it don't found the '<'

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): 410 Gone in

It is a [Http error code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

so

```
$body = $result->getBody();
```

don't return the right xml string

Try to visit: http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnacleFeed.aspx
And after try to visit: http://www.pinnaclesports.com/pinnacleFeed.aspx